# Knockout.js and datepicker valueAcessor function

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, datepicker

I'm having some problems with the the datepicker component bootstrap and the knockout.js.
I took a few examples and tested in my application and I am not able to understand the reason for this problem.
A fiddle that I found very useful but that ends up causing a problem is this http://jsfiddle.net/krainey/nxhqerxg/ where valueAcessor this example appears as a function (when I'm debugging can see it), but in my application is displayed the value of the object, and I think this is the problem so that it is not working in my application the way it should work.
In Chrome console I write valueAcessor() (I insert a debugger at the beginning of biding, specifically in row 3 of fiddle) and the console returns:

```
function d() {
    if (0 < length)
        return d.Pa(c, arguments[0]) && (d.X(), c = arguments[0], d.W()), this; a.k.Jb(d); return c
}
```

If I debug my application through the Chrome console, valueAcessor() returns me an empty string "" if I am entering a new data or a date that is already in the database if a previously registered record, and on line 18, ($ (element) .datepicker ('update' dataSource ())), because my valueAcessor() is a string and not a function, the error occurs "string is not a function".
Does anyone have any idea why this is happening in two different ways, given that the code is identical to the example?
I am using the same version of knockout, bootstrap and jquery that example.

Comment: are you sure that the value, which you are using in the binding, is a knockout observable?

Comment: I found the problem that was causing it. In my controller I was doing a .ToString ("MM / dd / yyyy"). Thank you for your help.